# Customise ActiveRecord JSON Response without a Serializer

Tags: json, api, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I'm rendering some JSON using sinatra/contrib. I want to customise my JSON response not to include "teacher_id" in the associated record. How do I do this?

```
get '/teachers' do
  json Teacher.includes(:courses).all.as_json(include: :courses)
end
```

Will render:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Dave",
  "age": 27,
  "specialism": "Ruby",
  "courses": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "WDI",
      "teacher_id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to remove, teacher_id:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Dave",
  "age": 27,
  "specialism": "Ruby",
  "courses": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "WDI"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can use the except: syntax to remove id, name, age and specialism. How can I remove the associated property?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:except` option for associations like this:

```
Teacher.includes(:courses).all
  .as_json(include: { courses: { except: :teacher_id } })
```